# Debug sudden load peaks

Tags: linux, high-load

I need to debug sudden load peaks automatically. We already monitor with nagios like check scripts, but the load peaks are seldom and short.

I search for a daemon which checks the load every N seconds and if there is trouble, reports something like `ps aux --forest` (and iotop --batch)

Graphs created with e.g. munin don't help here, since I need to identify the processes which cause the load.

Answer (score 1):

Amongst many possibilities for local process monitoring ([choose your poison](http://bodgeit.wikia.com/wiki/Linux_Process_Monitoring#Some_popular_Packages)) is [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html), I do something like this in `/etc/monit.d/system.conf` on centos machines;

```
check system localhost
    if loadavg (1min) > 6 then alert
    if loadavg (5min) > 6 then alert
    if memory usage > 90% then alert
    if cpu usage (user) > 90% then alert
    if cpu usage (system) > 75% then alert
    if cpu usage (wait) > 75% then alert
```

I imagine that you might want to be more aggressive with the checks, hence you might want to set the daemon to run checks more often, maybe every [30 seconds](http://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#daemon_mode) until you have determined the problem, and hence would use a `/etc/monit.conf` something like this;

```
set daemon  30
set mailserver localhost
#set alert user@gmail.com but not on { instance }
set alert user@gmail.com
include /etc/monit.d/*
set httpd port 2812
        allow 127.0.0.1
```

If monit does not provide enough information in the default mail alert, then you can have monit execute custom scripts on alert conditions like so;

```
check system localhost
    if loadavg (1min) > 6 then exec "/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/top -n1 -b  | /bin/mail -s top-output userXXX@gmail.com'"
    if loadavg (5min) > 6 then exec "/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/top -n1 -b  | /bin/mail -s top-output userXXX@gmail.com'"
    if cpu usage (user) > 90%  then exec "/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/top -n1 -b  | /bin/mail -s top-output userXXX@gmail.com'"
```

(obviously relies on mail command being setup, but you can use local root instead and just check it manually)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try it soon and post my experience here.

Comment: i did a quick test, and it seems that the alert email does include the offending pid of the process, so I have updated the answer with a debugging example to include the top output.

Answer (score 0):

`perf` is the way to go, it's commonly installed by default (`linux-tools` on Debian).

Use `perf top` to look at your problem interactively, then use `perf stat -p PID` to refine by PID. Look at the wiki to find more: https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I read the tutorial of `perf`. It is a great tool for debugging on linux. But I need a automated way to check for the load peaks. I can't inspect them live (logging via ssh and call `perf`). Please correct me if I am wrong, but AFAIK `perf` is not made for running in daemon mode and watching all processes.